# How to resolve Array to string conversion error

Tags: error

1. I'm sending a .ods file name into the makeFileName method to get a unique string value for the file name. but it return a file name which is not ending in .ods instead it end with `.unknown`.

   Ex: `template_ods_65c986571c9c2737fff370ce4a745015.unknown`

   but i need a file name like `template_65c986571c9c2737fff370ce4a745015.ods`.
2. Other thing is when i assign a returned string value into a variable, it gives me the array to string conversion error.
   **code**

   $newName = CRM_Utils_File::makeFileName($value['name']);

   **Error**

> Array to string conversion in
> /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php
> on line 554
>
> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array
> given in
> /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php
> on line 556

I confused with these two error, i'll appreciate if someone could help me to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you can go to Administer - System Settings - Safe File Extensions and add `.ods` to the list there.

For the second one is `$value['name']` actually a string or is it an array?